# How to stop Spring Scheduled task when certain condition is met

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I have some scheduled task:

```
@Component
class Task {
  @Scheduled(...)
  void exec() {
    doSmth();
    if (allDone) {
      // cancel task, it wont ever run again
    }
  } 
}
```

This is how I want this to look like. There are solutions on web, but they all seems to be rather complex and not quite work for me, while it seems to be rather common problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
     @Component
     class Task {
        private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

      @Value("${task.enable}")
      private boolean enableTask;

      @Override
      @Transactional(readOnly=true)
      @Scheduled(cron = "${task.schedule}")
      public void execute() {

           //Do something
          //can use DAO or other autowired beans here
          if(enableTask){
              Do your conditional job here...
          }
     }
     ...
     }
```

[java](/questions/tagged/java)  [spring](/questions/tagged/spring) [scheduled-tasks](/questions/tagged/scheduled-tasks)